# Difference between Feature ID and Solution ID

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, feature, solution-package

Is there a difference between Feature ID and Solution ID for any WSP package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution id is `identity of Solution package` (.wsp file). If you are deploying wsp file, it will check solution id. If exists, it will update solution.
Solution contains all the features, assembly, resources, etc.

```
One .wsp package can contain multiple features
```

Feature id is `identity of particular single feature` which is web/site/web application/farm scoped feature. 
Feature contains scope related resources.

For example, list definitions and list instances are included in Web scope feature.
             WebPart files are included in Site scope feature.

Comment: just add to your answer **One `.wsp` package can contain multiple features**

Answer (score 3):

**Solution Id-**

- A WSP contains unique / single Solution ID.
- One solution / WSP can contains **many feature ID's**, depending on the requirement.

**Feature ID-**
 - Feature Id can be multiple in a single solution(Site/Web level fetures)

Answer (score 2):

**Solution ID:** ID of the Package (.wsp file), That are you going todeploy

1. Open the solution package file in VS
2. Click on the package designer
3. Open the Property window and scroll down the the Solution ID value
4. Change the Id to a different Guid

[image]

**Fature ID:** The SharePoint ID of the Feature. Feature have scope like web/site/web application/farm scoped feature.

1. Open the solution package file in VS
2. Click Feature
3. Open the Property window and scroll down the the Feature ID value
4. Change the Id to a different Guid

[image]